# I want to add a link as value in multiple select

Tags: php, select, hyperlink, echo, multi-select

```
if($_GET['tags'] == true){echo'
<select data-placeholder="'. $xml->tags .'" name="tags[]" class="chzn-select" multiple tabindex="4">';
$ergebnis = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM login");
while($row = mysql_fetch_object($ergebnis))
{echo'<option value="<a href=\''. $row->username .' ('. $row->fname .')\'>'. $row->username .'</a>">'. $row->username .' ('. $row->fname .')</option>';}
echo'
</select><br/><br/>';}
```

It always shows the link in the select area! 
What should I do??

Comment: Can you maybe add some details to your question to make it more understandable?

Comment: it doesnt post the value in the mysql

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
echo'<option value="<a href=\''. $row->username .' ('. $row->fname .')\'>'. $row->username .'</a>">'. $row->username .' ('. $row->fname .')</option>';
```

`value="<a href="(...)`

You opened value attribute and immediately closed it.

Comment: What? Please explain again... Previously you said "it always shows the link in the select area", now it works, so what is the problem?

Comment: it doesnt post the value in the mysql

Comment: But that code gets everything from login table and print `<select>` tag, there is nothing that would add value to database... Are you sure what are you doing?